# Execute function in string format

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a array function in os module, how can i loop through and execute each function.

```
var os = require("os");

var os_func_list = Object.keys(os);

os_func_list.forEach(function(element) {

    // I know this is not working
    // var func = "os." + element + "()";
    // console.log(func);
}, this);
```

Answer:

```
os_func_list.forEach(function(element) {
    var func = os[element];
    if (typeof func === 'function') { //verify that value is a function
        console.log(func());
    }
}, this);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[]` notation to dynamically access the properties/functions on an object:

```
var os = require("os");

var os_func_list = Object.keys(os);

os_func_list.forEach(function(element) {
  var osValue = os[element];
  if (typeof osValue === 'function') { //verify that value is a function
    osValue();
  }
});
```

If you need to use a specific `this` value during the calls (since I notice you were careful to pass `this` as the second argument to `forEach`), you can use `call`. Just change:

```
osValue();
```

to

```
osValue.call(appropriateValueForThisGoesHere);
```

Comment: I getting a error: func is not a function, the same with the answert above

Comment: we'll need to check if `os[element]` is a function - there are some strings, etc. will update answer

Comment: @gnoohtuk: As far as we could tell from your question, you were expecting all of `os`'s properties to be functions. If some of them aren't, then as hackerdave has shown, you need a guard.

Comment: it worked, thanks both of you. hackerrdave T.J. Crowder. I will update my question.

Answer (score -1):

One VERY dangerous solution could be to use the `eval()` function :

```
var functionName = 'foo' 
eval(functionName + '()')
```

I know that in web page context, you can use `window[functionName]()` but because you're executing a node script, I'm not sure if this object is available.